# How to convert a string into a specific array

Tags: php, arrays, salesforce, salesforce-chatter

Using PHP, how do I convert this string:

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 00541000004UDewAAG consectetur adipiscing elit 00541000003WKoEAAW  eiusmod tempor incididunt 00541000003WKmiAA";
```

Into an array like this:

```
$messageSegments = [
 ["type" => "Text", "text" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet "], 
 ["type" => "Mention", "id" => "00541000004UDewAAG"], 
 ["type" => "Text", "text" => "consectetur adipiscing elit"], 
 ["type" => "Mention", "id" => "00541000003WKoEAAW"], 
 ["type" => "Text", "text" => "eiusmod tempor incididunt"], 
 ["type" => "Mention", "id" => "00541000003WKmiAA"], 
];
```

The type "Mention" always has this format: "00541000003WKoEAAW" which is a [Salesforce ID](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of) while everything else is regular text..

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _always has this format_ So always starts with 0054? Always is the same number of numbers then uppercase letters then lower then upper?  What are the format rules?

Comment: The first 3 characters refers to the object type in Saleforce - which is a user. So yes, it should be 005 always.

Comment: And the rest???

Comment: This is clearly doable, but the obvious question is: What have you tried?

Comment: You can use preg_split to start with.

Comment: I've tried explode() - but can't put the segments back into the array that i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use preg_split() + combining two arrays. This solves the issue of text getting chopped off - if the ID is in the beginning of the string, etc.

```
    $ids = [];
    $words = [];
    $final = [];

    $pattern = '/005[a-zA-Z|0-9]{15}/'; 
    $exploded = explode(' ', $text); 

    //get all the mention ids from new text
    foreach ($exploded as $index => $word) {
        if(preg_match($pattern, $exploded[$index])){
            //replace period or comma
            $id = str_replace(',','',str_replace('.','',$exploded[$index])); 
            array_push($ids,$id);
        }
    } 
    //get words array
    $words = preg_split($pattern, $text,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 

    //find which is first: id or words
    $isIdFirst = preg_match('/^005/', $text); //if str starts with 005

    if($isIdFirst){
        for($x=0; $x < count($ids); $x++) {  
           array_push($final, ['type'=>'Mention','id'=>$ids[$x]]);
           if(isset($words[$x])){
                array_push($final, ['type'=>'Text', 'text'=>$words[$x]]);
           }
        }
    }else{
        for($x=0; $x < count($words); $x++) {  
            array_push($final, ['type'=>'Text', 'text'=>$words[$x]]);
            if(isset($ids[$x])){
                array_push($final, ['type'=>'Mention','id'=>$ids[$x]]);
            }
         }
    }  
    var_dump($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode function http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
     $str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 00541000004UDewAAG consectetur adipiscing elit 00541000003WKoEAAW  eiusmod tempor incididunt 00541000003WKmiAA";
    $array = explode(' ', $str);
    $generated = array();
     $y = "";
    for($x= 0; $x < sizeOf($array); $x++){
        if (substr($array[$x], 0, 3) != '005') {
       $y .= ' ' . $array[$x]; //CONCAT WORDS
     } else {
    $temp = array("type" => "Text", "text" => $y); //create the text array
    $temp2 = array("type" => "Mention", "id" => $array[$x]); //create the id array
       array_push($generated, $temp, $temp2); //then push it
     $temp = array(); //make array null
         $temp2 = array(); 
          $y = null; //and null
     }
   }
   print_r($generated);
```

Comment: this comes out to: (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Text
            [text] =>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => Mention
            [id] => 00541000004UDewAAG
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => Text
            [text] =>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => Mention
            [id] => 00541000003WKoEAAW
        )

)

Comment: I need the text array to continue where it last left off...Like: (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Text
            [text] =>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => Mention
            [id] => 00541000004UDewAAG
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => Text
            [text] =>  consectetur adipiscing elitelit
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => Mention
            [id] => 00541000003WKoEAAW
        )

)

Comment: i just saw that you revised your answer. And I checked it and it works as well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 00541000004UDewAAG consectetur adipiscing elit 00541000003WKoEAAW eiusmod tempor incididunt 00541000003WKmiAA";

$startWith = '005';

$exploded = explode(' ', $str);
$result = [];
$lastIndex = 0;

foreach ($exploded as $index => $word) {
    if (strpos($word, $startWith) === 0) {
        $textExploded = array_filter(array_slice($exploded, $lastIndex, $index - $lastIndex));
        $result = array_merge($result, [
            ['type' => 'Text', 'text' => implode(' ', $textExploded)],
            ['type' => 'Mention', 'id' => $word]
        ]);

        if (isset($exploded[$index +1])) {
            $lastIndex = $index + 1;
        }
    }
}

//var_dump($result);
```